# Difference between: MobX and Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, mobx

- What is the difference?
- What is better library in React or React-Native between MobX and Redux until heavy project from small?

Comment: Single store vs multiple store
plain data vs observable data
Mutable vs imutable

Comment: My answer to this question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51813683/741657) might help you understand better. (read the question too, to get the context)

Answer (score -1):

```html
Redux
• Large community, so lots of resources available online
• Conceptually simple, clean abstractions
• Matured dev tools
• functional programming oriented, which offers cool benefits like time travelling, trivial action testing and such
• Actions and state changes are very traceable
• Rigid paradigm to work in (which is generally speaking a good thing)
MobX
• Very efficient out of the box (applies side-ways-loading without needing selectors etc)
• Very suitable for a state tree that has lot of inter data relationships; the data doesn't need to be normalized to a tree
• More OO oriented; you can use classes, instance methods etc..; less new concepts to learn
• UI is always kept up to date
• no flux like action dispatching required (although you could still do that). On large apps this saves tremendous amounts of boilerplate
• actions are really straightforward; you don't have to return new data structures etc. You can just alter objects and the changes are picked up automatically
• Functional reactive programming oriented
• Simpler to work with async actions
```

[Redux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNklm.png)

[Mobx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4Tul.png)

Comment: The answer lists somebody else's answer without attribution. Code snippet isn't a proper way to format regular text. Images should be formatted as images, not links, preferably with a link where they come from.

Answer (score -1):

Well the major difference between them is, there's a lot of boilerplate code in Redux while Mobx saves you from that (Internally it does it for you in the best possible and optimal way). Redux gives you a lot of flexibility while defining the flow of data as compared to MobX.